# mapdist limited to <200 requests

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, ggmap

I've recently been playing with the mapdist function in the ggmap package.

For small volumes of queries it works fine for me, but for larger numbers (still below the 2,500 limit) it falls over and I'm not sure why.

I've had an old colleague try this script and they get the same results as I do (they are in a different organisation, using a different computer, on a different network etc.).

Here is my testing script which runs the same request again and again to see how many queries it manages to pass before failing. It was consistently returning 129 for a time, lately it has begun returning 127 (though this number is still consistent within a certain test).

Note that although this repeats the same postcodes, I have tried similar with a random selection of destination postcodes and get the same results.

```
library("ggmap")

# Setup ----------
no.of.pcd.to.check <- 500
a <- rep("SW1A 1AA",no.of.pcd.to.check) # Use a repeating list of the same postcode to remove it as a causal factor
b <- rep("WC2H 0HE",no.of.pcd.to.check) # As above

test.length <- 5 # How many iterations should the test run over

# Create results dataframe ----------
# and pre-set capacity to speed up the for loop
results.df <- data.frame(
                 Iteration=seq(1:test.length), 
                 Result=as.integer(rep(0,test.length)),
                 Remaining=as.integer(rep(0,test.length))) 


# Run the test ----------

for(i in 1:test.length){
      x <- distQueryCheck() # Get remaining number of queries pre submission
      try(mapdist(a, b, mode="driving", output="simple",override_limit=TRUE))
      y <- distQueryCheck() # Get remaining number of queries post submission
      query.use <- (x-y) # Difference between pre and post (ie number of successful queries submitted)
      print(paste(query.use, "queries used"))
      results.df[i,"Result"] <- query.use # Save successful number of queries for each test iteration
      results.df[i,"Remaining"] <- y
}
```

I'd be really grateful for any insight on where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: This is somewhat speculative, but, looking at the code for `mapdist(...)`, the function tests if the request url is >2048 characters. If it is, `mapdist(...)` calls itself recursively with 1/2 the postal codes, until it gets to < 2048 chars in the request. The error you're getting is "subscript out of bounds", which I think is a failure in that loop.

Comment: Also, you should be aware that the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) restrict you to < 100 elements per query and < 100 elements per 10 seconds, as well as < 2500 element per day.

Answer (score 0):

So I had this same error message, and what ended up fixing it was simply changing the '#' in an address to 'Number '.  I'm no expert and haven't even looked into the mapdist code, but eliminating '#' allowed me to use mapdist with no problems.